# How to Display files(images) in react front-end their names fetched from mongoDb and they are store on server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I have web application with Mern. it's working good with json data. i just used files in my projects i can upload files front-end to back-end through multer middle-ware and storing  on server and saving their name in mongoDb database.

so when i fetch data from back-end normal data is working well but when i try to display files that are just displaying name that are stored in database not displaying actual image so i'm stuck. how to show images in front-end that are stored in back-end and their names i fetched from mongodb?

this is fetched data form db and displaying in front-end.

```
  `const { name, email, phone, protype, date, description, _id, file } = pro;`
```

but when i want to display images or files it's just showing files name that is in database. This is how i am displaying.

```
<span className='data'>
      <img src={file} alt='images' />
</span>
```

i don't know how to give path of folder that is on server where files stored.

Comment: 2 way, 1) when you send files in back-end save files relation name and path in database where your files can be accessible with url and when you fetch data then send files with full url path, 2) after saving files in back-end when you fetch data you can read files in back-end and convert to base64 and send to front for showing !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save the file on the server, you should store the whole file URL in your MongoDB database, because then you can just reference it like you've already done.

So, instead of just saving the name of the file, you should save the file URL. Ex: `https://example.com/img/1234.jpg`

Comment: is there any article on this? actually not getting what is image url if u have any ex kindly show

Comment: You store the file on your server somewhere. The URL of that exact file location is the file URL. You need that to display the image

Comment: The example I gave would mean that you had a server with a domain of `example.com`, where the file is stored in the `/img` folder and called `1234.jpg`

Comment: http://localhost:5000/public/projectfiles/Screenshot (3).png-1577523441396

Comment: so how i'll display this in fron end

Comment: You send the file URL with the JSON data - you destructure some stuff from the `pro` variable, then the `file` variable would be the file URL

Comment: yes i destructured and displaying that like this     ` <span className='data'>
                                                                             <img src={file} alt='files' />
                                                                              </span>`

Comment: but still not displaying

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log` the value of `file`?

Comment: `http://localhost:5000/public/images/projectfiles/Screenshot (9).png-1577524140867`

Comment: and then this    `http://localhost:5000/public/images/projectfiles/Screenshot%20(9).png-1577524140867 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: url of file in db is    `http://localhost:5000/public/images/projectfiles/nightlight.jpg-1577524460616`

Comment: What happens if you open the URL of the file (`http://localhost:5000/public/images/projectfiles/Screenshot (9).png-1577524140867` or what it is)?

Comment: folder structure of server is like this..      `unitecx > server.js and other folder including public`

Comment: Cannot GET /public/images/projectfiles/Screenshot%20(9).png-1577524140867

Comment: You said that the URL of the file in the db is `http://localhost:5000/public/images/projectfiles/nightlight.jpg-1577524460616`, but you're referencing another file `http://localhost:5000/public/images/projectfiles/Screenshot (9).png-1577524140867`. You should maybe try uploading the file again

Comment: still not showing btw thank you soo much for valueable conversation now i'll fix that tysm